# Embedded components in Visualforce tabs

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have several Visualforce component pages that are referenced in apex:tab tags. The components query for fields on an associate child object and its fields. The components are not remaining in the tabs and are either listed below or to the right of the page. How can I get the component to remain in the tab they belong to?

Below is the tab panel and a sample query from the first component.

```
<apex:actionRegion immediate="true" >

<apex:outputPanel id="OutputLOBTabPanel"> 
<b><apex:outputText style="font-style:bold;color:blue" value="Selected Line of Business Analysis - Choose LOB to display in General Section. * indicates incomplete business definition."   /> </b> 
<br></br>
<apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theLOBTabPanel" headerClass="tabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" >

<apex:tab label="Non Standard Auto" name="tabLOB1" id="tabLOB1" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'NonStandardAuto'),"true","false")}" > 
<c:PROD_CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto NonStdAuto="{!LOB_NonStdAuto}" /> 
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="Workers Comp" name="tabLOB2" id="tabLOB2" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'WorkersComp'),"true","false")}" > 
<c:PROD_CCRA_LOB_WorkersComp LOB_WorkersComp="{!LOB_WorkersComp}" /> 
<b><apex:outputText style="font-style:bold;color:blue" value="Rollup of NonStdAuto record ID"  /> </b> 
<apex:outputField value="{!Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Rollup_LOB_NonStdAuto__c}"  />
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="Commercial Auto" name="tabLOB3" id="tabLOB3" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'CommercialAuto'),"true","false")}" >
<c:PROD_CCRA_LOB_CommAuto LOB_CommAuto="{!LOB_CommAuto}" /> 
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="Umbrella" name="tabLOB4" id="tabLOB4" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'Umbrella'),"true","false")}">
<c:PROD_CCRA_LOB_Umbrella LOB_Umbrella="{!LOB_Umbrella}" /> 
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="Comm Property / *HO" name="tabLOB5" id="tabLOB5" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'CommercialProperty'),true,false) || 
IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'Homeowners'),true,false)}" >
<c:PROD_CCRA_LOB_Property LOB_Property="{!LOB_Property}" /> 
</apex:tab>


<apex:tab label="*Homeowners" name="tabLOB6" id="tabLOB6" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'Homeowners'),"true","false")}" >
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="*General Liability" name="tabLOB7" id="tabLOB7" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'GeneralLiability'),"true","false")}" >
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="*Equipment Breakdown" name="tabLOB8" id="tabLOB8" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'EquipmentBreakdown'),"true","false")}" >
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="*AH" name="tabLOB9" id="tabLOB9" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'AH'),"true","false")}" >
</apex:tab>

<apex:tab label="*Personal Auto" name="tabLOB10" id="tabLOB10" rendered="{!IF(CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'PersonalAuto'),"true","false")}" >
</apex:tab>

<!----------------------END OF LOB TAB PANEL-----------------------> 
</apex:tabPanel>
</apex:outputPanel>
</apex:actionRegion>


public void getLOB_NonStdAuto() {    
        try {
            this.LOB_NonStdAuto = queryLOB_NonStdAuto(this.CCRA.Id);
System.debug('LOB_NonStdAuto query Result : ' + this.LOB_NonStdAuto);            
            } catch (Exception ex) {
            ApexPages.addMessages(ex);
            }        
        }


    Private CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c queryLOB_NonStdAuto(Id CCRA_ID) {    
    LOB_NonStdAuto = [
        SELECT 
            Id
            ,Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c
            ,CreatedDate
            ,CreatedById
            ,LastModifiedById
            ,LastModifiedDate
            ,Average_Cycle_Time_BI_PY__c
            ,Average_Cycle_Time_BI_YTD__c
            ,Average_Cycle_Time_Collision_PY__c
            ,Average_Cycle_Time_Collision_YTD__c

        FROM 
            CCRA_LOB_NonStdAuto__c 
        WHERE 
            IsDeleted = false 
            AND 
            Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c = :CCRA_ID 
        ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC NULLS FIRST LIMIT 1
   ];  

        return LOB_NonStdAuto;    
    }
```

[image]

**This is the component structure. Used component that is shifted to right pane.**

```
    <apex:component >
        <!-- Attribute Definitions -->
        <apex:attribute name="LOB_WorkersComp" type="CCRA_LOB_WorkersComp__c" description="CCRA Workers Comp LOB" required="true"/>

    <!--Contoller Information variables --> 
    <apex:variable var="LOB" value="{!LOB_WorkersComp}" /> 

    <apex:stylesheet value="{!URLFOR($Resource.cssresource_ClaimCCRA, 'CSSresource_ClaimsCCRA.css')}"/> 

    <apex:pageMessages id="globalMessages" rendered="false"/>
    <apex:messages title="data incorrectly entered." style="background-color:yellow; color: blue" /> 

    <apex:form id="form1">
    <!--Buttons -->
    <apex:commandButton value="Save Only WC" action="{!Save}" styleClass="button" style="background:lightblue;color:blue;border-radius:15px;" />

    <apex:pageBlock id="block1" dir="" >


    <apex:outputPanel >
    <apex:outputText value="{0,date} {0,time}">
    <b>Created: </b> &nbsp;  <apex:param value="{!LOB.CreatedDate}"/>  
    </apex:outputText> 
    by: &nbsp; <apex:outputField value="{!LOB.CreatedById}"/> &nbsp; <b> Last Modified By: </b>  <apex:outputField value="{!LOB.LastModifiedById}"/>  on &nbsp; 
    <apex:outputField value="{!LOB.LastModifiedDate}"/>
     </apex:outputPanel> 

    <apex:outputPanel > 
    <p><b>Hello {!$User.FirstName}!</b> &nbsp; <font color='blue'> Enter Workers Comp Information Below. </font> </p><br></br>
     </apex:outputPanel>


    <apex:actionRegion immediate="true" >

    <apex:outputPanel id="OutputTabPanel"> 
    <b><apex:outputText style="font-style:bold;color:blue" value="Workers Comp Data"  /> </b> 
    <br></br>
    CCRA MSTR Detail Name : &nbsp; &nbsp; <apex:outputField value="{!LOB.Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c}"/>
    <br></br>
**<!-- <apex:tabPanel switchType="client" selectedTab="name2" id="theTabPanel" headerClass="tabPanel" tabClass="activeTab" inactiveTabClass="inactiveTab" > --> **

    <apex:outputText style="font-style:italic;color:blue" value="Workers Comp Information. " /> 

    <apex:outputPanel Style="width:100%;" layout="block">
        <apex:pageBlockSection id="Summary" title="" columns="2" showHeader="false" >

    <!-- ********* -->
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >
                        <apex:outputLabel value="Nurse Case Managers Used"  StyleClass="col1"   />   
                        <apex:inputField value="{!LOB.Nurse_Case_Mgrs_Used__c}" styleClass="col2" /> 
                       </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

                     <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="col"  >                         
                             <apex:outputLabel value=""   /> 
                     </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
    <!-- ********* -->

    <!-- ************** MORE fields.....**************** -->

    </apex:pageBlockSection>
    </apex:outputPanel>

    <!----------------------END OF TAB PANEL-----------------------> 
**<!-- </apex:tabPanel> -->** 
    </apex:outputPanel>
    </apex:actionRegion>
    <!----------------------#######----------------------->
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
    <!-- End  -->
    </apex:component>
```

Comment: Share the screenshot of the UI.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you can simplify your rendered logic: `rendered="{!CONTAINS(Claims_Client_Risk_Assessment__c.Lines_of_Business__c,'WorkersComp')}"`. It'd make your code a bit easier to read.

Comment: Thanks sfdcfox. I had been using that syntax but often when using OR / AND conditional statements for rendering it seemed like the literal true/false syntax behaved better. Or maybe its just me.

Comment: @TusharSharma I added the screen shot. Shows one tab (Workers Comp) off to the right and another (Umbrella) below the set of tabs .

Comment: did you try wrapping your components in `apex:outputPanel` ?

Comment: Interesting. When I stripped out most of the html and Visualforce tags into cloned components the component calls in each tab behave. Meaning they stay in the tab and do not shift out of it. So I'm thinking that maybe the component outputPanel,.... is causing the component to show in it's own frame ?

Comment: @cropredy  do you mean wrapping the call for the component with outputPanels ?

Comment: @cropredy tried wrapping the called component in outputPanels. Problem persist. <apex:outputPanel >
<c:PROD_CCRA_LOB_WorkersComp LOB_WorkersComp="{!LOB_WorkersComp}" /> 
</apex:outputPanel>

Comment: @sfdcfox Discovered issue. Each Visualforce component also had a <apex:tabPanel> with no tabs. This was a carry over from cloning. So when the component was instructed to open in the parent (CCRA) tab it was trying to open another <apex:tabPanel>. Removing the <apex:tabPanel from each component now allows the paent <apex:tabPanel to properly display each component in its unique tab. Marked tab panels removed on component code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Discovered issue. Each Visualforce component also had a  with no tabs. This was a carry over from cloning. So when the component was instructed to open in the parent (CCRA) tab it was trying to open another . Removing the